# rake test:prepare doesn't create test database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I'm on Rails 3.2.9 and when I try to run the following commands

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate test:prepare
rspec spec/
```

The `rspec` commands throws an error

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'app_test.articles' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `articles` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

But when I run the `test:prepare` command seperatly, it works:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate
rake test:prepare
rspec spec/
```

> Why does preparing the test database in the same rake command not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the environment information. Like `RAILS_ENV=test`.
Please try this:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:test:prepare
```

Comment: This is exactly what `test:prepare` is intended to do

Comment: Then try with `rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate db:test:prepare`

Comment: Same result, there is no difference between `test:prepare` and `db:test:prepare`

Comment: Specifically, `rake db:test:prepare` will do the following:

1. Check for pending migrations and,
2. and load the test schema

Comment: You can also add `rake db:drop db:setup RAILS_ENV=test`.It will drop the db then create the db and migrate the db also.